# Android App shows data for a split second before login page is shown

Tags: android

I have the logging in and logging out process somewhat working correctly, I'm using api token auth but when the app loads it seems to have a slight glitch. When the user isn't logged in and the app opens you can see the data for a split second and then the login activity opens up, however that shouldn't happen because that info is not supposed to be seen by someone not logged in, and is different for each user that logs in.

This is how I'm doing it 
MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        User user = SharedPreferencesHelper.getUser(MainActivity.this);

        if (user.getToken() == null) {
            Intent login = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(login);
        }

        //still in testing but the sensitive data would be in here
        textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
        textViewResult.setText("Lorem Ipsum....");

        //logout function
        logoutBtn = findViewById(R.id.logoutbtn);
        logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Call<Void> call = apiInterface.LogoutUser(user.getToken());

                call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
                    //stuff
                });


            }
        });
```

The login data is in the LoginActivity.java and it gets called only when the user token is null (no logged in user).

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Is `getToken()` really just a call to an entry in SharedPreferences? If it's a call to a database, it can take a while.

An easy way to prevent your activity from showing before you evaluate the login is to move `setContentView()` after the login evaluation like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        User user = SharedPreferencesHelper.getUser(MainActivity.this);
        if (user.getToken() == null) {
            Intent login = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(login);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
}
```

Comment: When the user logs in I save all their data to SharedPreferences and the getToken just gets the saved user's token from SharedPreferences user, if it returns null it's because no one is logged in

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you don't want to show MainActivity for a user who's not logged in, correct?

In this case, I suggest you create a Splash Screen Activity. A Splash Screen is a screen that opens right away when your user clicks on the app, while the app loads. You can put a background image in this activity, for example. This Splash Activity would be the first activity opened by your app, and then, on it's onCreate method, you can verify if user is logged in and redirect him accordingly.

[Here's a very simple and good tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/launch-screen-in-android-the-right-way-aca7e8c31f52) for creating a SplashScreen in Android.

I hope suggestion is adequate!

Comment: the link says 404 not found :(

Comment: Sorry, try now!